# Summing an array of integers in C

Tags: c, arrays

I have read the answers to questions already asked here about summing arrays and still can't see where I've got it wrong. I am trying to sum an array. The code I have written gives me an output, just not the correct one! This is my code:

```
int main() {
    int x; 
    scanf("%d",&x);
    int array[x];
    int sum = 0; 
    for (int i = 0; i < x; i++) {
        scanf("%d", &array[i]);
    }
    for (int i = 0; i < x; i++) {
        sum += sum + array[i]; 
    }
    printf("%d\n", sum);
    return 0;
}
```

Can anyone see where I've gone wrong?

Thanks

Comment: sum += array[i]

Comment: `sum = sum + array[i];` or `sum += array[i]`

Comment: What's wrong with this Question? It was a fair Question. Please stop Down voting people just because you don't like the Question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should either write `sum += array[i];` or `sum = sum + array[i];`.  The way it is written, you do not compute the sum of values (except for trivial cases such as `0` and `1` value).

Answer (score 0):

Hope this helps I explain the various steps through comments:

```
#include <stdio.h>

/* 
    Good practice to use a symbolic name to represent 
    the number of elements in an array that way if you 
    have to change the number of elements you just have 
    to do it here.
*/ 
#define NO_OF_ELEMENTS 5

int main()
{
    // Declare variables and initialize them to 0.
    int i = 0, sum = 0;
    int array[NO_OF_ELEMENTS] = {0}; // Initializes all elements to 0.

    for(i = 0; i < NO_OF_ELEMENTS; i++)
    {
        printf("Enter number %d: ", i + 1); // +1 so i doesnt appear as 0 on first loop.
        scanf("%d", &array[i]);
        sum += array[i]; // Calculate sum.
    }

    printf("Sum of elements: %d", sum); // Display sum.

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: I hope the OP learns from your commented code, but his code implements different semantics: the first input is the number of further inputs to sum. If you are going to post sample code, make it fit the OP's needs.  I agree it is unwise to use a VLA from an unchecked size typed by the user... but it is also bad practice to not check the return value of `scanf`.